# Transforming Enter key pressed event into tab key pressed event in custom textbox (it has to be multibrowser)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

We have a dll of custom web controls based on the System.Web.UI ones. I've been asked to make it so when the user hits enter, the tab event would be fired instead. I've done this:

```
Me.Attributes.Remove("onkeydown")
Me.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "if(event.keyCode == 13) {event.keyCode = 9; return event.keyCode;}")
If Me.TextMode = Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.MultiLine Then
   Me.Attributes.Remove("onkeydown")
End If
```

But it only works on IE. When i tested it on FF and Chrome, the enter event generates postback. I've tried other solutions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function catchEnter(e){
   var theKey=0;
   e=(window.event)?event:e;
   theKey=(e.keyCode)?e.keyCode:e.charCode;
   if(theKey=="13"){ // 13 is the key code for ENTER
      // here is where your code will go
      //return false; // return false if you want to...
      //...halt submission of form (call this function onsubmit)
   }
}
</script>



function checkKey(e) {
    var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
    if (true) {
        alert(event.keyCode)
    }
}
```

And also:

```
function displayunicode(e){
var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
```

But i have to use Attributes.Add to insert the javascript. I can write down a whole javascript function using Attributes.Add? When i try to use these functions, i ignore the 'script' tags and only put the javascript code. Am i doing something wrong here?

Which one of these codes would work? (IE, FF and Chrome)

Comment: _"Which one of these codes would work? (IE, FF and Chrome)"_ Which ones did you try?

Comment: All of them. But i did add them using Attributes.Add.

I did something like this:

Attributes.Add("onkeydown","var theKey=0;
   e=(window.event)?event:e;
   theKey=(e.keyCode)?e.keyCode:e.charCode;
   if(theKey=="13"){ // 13 is the key code for ENTER
      // here is where your code will go
      //return false; // return false if you want to...
      //...halt submission of form (call this function onsubmit)
   }"

Oh yeah, i'm using onkeydown property.